# Make UIView Background Transparent and Its Subviews Non-Transparent

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

When I run my project, everything seems to be fine but the `UIViews` Background color still stays solid white when I used this code:

```
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Don't really no what else to try, I've looked on google and tried some other things but was told this code should do it but no luck.

Comment: How about `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`?

Comment: @Linuxios, hi, i have tried that also, that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the view behind `self.view` is not just white? What view is behind `self.view`. Is it the window?

Comment: First when the app loads you see a tableview, once you click the cell the Solid white uiview which needs to be transparent is shown with a web view

Comment: @redoc01 
do you check the IbOutlet to your View

Comment: when you click on a cell in the tableview i run this code [self presentModalViewController:youtubeVideoInfoViewController animated:YES]; that opens the UIView that needs the background to be transparent

Comment: layer background should be set to `CGColor` instance, not `UIColor`. Try `[UIColor clearColor].CGColor`.

Comment: @yurish, nope that cgcolor didn't work

Comment: This is a view controller's `view` property isn't it?

Comment: @0x7fffffff, hi, I'm new to iPhone development, so please go easy, but yes it is the view controllers property

Comment: @redoc01 See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller

Comment: @0x7fffffff, hi, you were right that link helped. But there is another problem i have set self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; in the viewdidload of the tableview controller view, but when the second view controller goes transparent the tableview is not functional

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409338/536214

Comment: Check this [code][1] and [a little correction of the previous][2] here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409338/536214
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3509030/536214

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this kind of code in your app delegate:

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

try chaining the colour from clear to translucent or another colour if it changes then your code for the view background colour is working as it should.